# How do I total up "yes's" from a column, by a userlevel and only for the past week? Using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I hopefully have a simple question I just cannot get anything I try to work.

Basically I am looking for a way to simply count the yes's in each column where user level = a number and by username = a user name in the past week starting on monday. Also for a way to total the amounts in the amounttot column.

My SQL Database is set up like below:

**DB Name**: 1_1 **Table:** form_2

*Sample of data in DB*

```
username userlevel inspect signatu claimnum amounttot timestamp
-------- --------- ------- ------- -------- --------- ---------
BobS     7         yes     yes     kj98739  5388.00   2011-10-15 16:39:20
SteveN   8         yes     no      kj76739  5000.00   2011-10-15 15:29:00
TimK     7         no      yes     kj98734  6000.00   2011-10-15 14:35:06
```

How I have it list all data per team, I just need to get totals below this print out in a completely different table I can just place below it., how can I get this to only show the last weeks data starting on a monday:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","1_1","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("1_1", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE userlevel = '5' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><font size='1'>Name</th>
<th><font size='1'>Latitude</th>
<th><font size='1'>Longatude</th>
<th><font size='1'>Inspect</th>
<th><font size='1'>Sig</th>
<th><font size='1'>Phone #</th>
<th><font size='1'>Insur</th>
<th><font size='1'>Claim</th>
<th><font size='1'>Appr</th>
<th><font size='1'>AdjusApp</th>
<th><font size='1'>Check</th>
<th><font size='1'>Amount</th>
<th><font size='1'>Time</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['username'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['lat'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['longa'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['inspect'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['signatu'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['gotphone'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['hain'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['claimnum'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['approved'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['adjustapprov'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['checkcollec'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['amounttot'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</font></td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
SELECT userlevel, COUNT(*)
FROM form_2
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN x AND y
AND signatu = 'yes'
GROUP BY userlevel
```

The 'x' and 'y' need to be the timestamps delimiting the query - they can be supplied by PHP or looked up directly in MySQL.

Edit: fixed query, thanks to @knittl.